# How to force Hibernate to detect table changes (e.g. maintenance)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

We are using the ff:

Hibernate version: 5.2.x
JPA version: 2.1

We have an app and production deployment is near. We found one minor problem.

This is what the client wants: Whenever they do maintenance on the materialized views and tables, they temporarily remove access rights of the db accounts we use in our datasources. They want users using the app to be informed when maintenance is currently being done. What happens is instead of our DAO throwing exceptions due to this, it just returns an empty result set of queries. We want our DAO classes to be able to catch this exception so we can inform users that db maintenance is in progress. We don't want to confuse the users that his/her data had been lost.

If our application is restarted in the app server, it is able to catch the exception. That is where the problem is - you need to restart the app for it to catch the exception. Is there anything we can do in hibernate to be able to catch this? without restarting.

Comment: Why are you not able to catch the exceptions? The DB driver will simply throw a SQLException. If you are using Oracle it will be ora-00942 table or view does not exist

Comment: Are you using the second level cache with query cache by chance?